# How to interpret $\hat{n}$?

Tags: electrostatics, vectors, gauss-law, dielectric

This is a problem I've been having with a lot of different physics concepts in my electrodynamics class. I've never truly understood what $\hat{n}$ is. I understand that it is the "normal unit vector", but when it comes to applying it in problems I am sort of hesitant.

For example, if you have a sphere of radius R, with polarization $\vec{P}(\vec{r})=k\vec{r}$ the bound surface charge is $\sigma_b=\vec{P}\cdot\hat{n}$.

So my interpretation of this is if I want to find the bound charge, I already have $\vec{P}$, so I need the unit vector which is normal to the surface... Seeing as how this is a radial surface, I would assume the $\hat{n}$ is $\hat{r}$. This would then make $$\sigma_b=k\vec{r}\cdot \hat{r}=k(\frac{\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|})=k(\frac{|\vec{r}|^2}{|\vec{r}|})=k|\vec{r}|$$
The book, however, is saying $\sigma_b = kR.$ Is R the same thing as $|\vec{r}| $? I'm not sure if my thought process is correct, or if I'm just misinterpreting something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.
The left hand diagram is for a general surface $S$.
The evaluation of the dot product is easier if the unit vector $\hat n$ is parallel to the polarisation vector $\vec P$ and it looks as though that in this case $|\vec r| = R$

[image]

Which book are you using?

Comment: Thank you!,
Griffiths - Introduction to Electrodynamics, 4th ed.

Comment: Example 4.2 is worth a look.